# Unwanted cursor with Java2D drawing directly to framebuffer

Tags: java, graphics2d, framebuffer

The environment is Java 11 on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with a 3.5" touchscreen. The program writes directly to the framebuffer with the aid of Thomas Welsch's [JavaFrameBuffer](https://github.com/ttww/JavaFrameBuffer) JNI support.

Things work as expected, except that a blinking cursor appears on the screen after drawing some text. This app uses no input except screen touches, so a cursor is irrelevant and visually disturbing.

How can I get rid of it?

Please note that no Component is present, so there is no `setCursor` method available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the lack of a component prohibits the easiest way of hiding the cursor with setCursor.

I tried the following in the cmdline.txt:

```
vt.global_cursor_default=0
```

(do not forget to reboot ^^)

Comment: The pickle makes the hamburger! Problem solved.